# Python subproccess.run isn't working with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, pyinstaller

Consider the following python (3.9) script, called test.py:

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

# This is for pyinstaller (as main_dir = sys.path[0] won't work)
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    main_dir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
else:
    main_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

processes_dir = Path(main_dir, "processes")
outfile = Path(main_dir, "output.txt")

# Initialize the output text file
with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
    f.write('')

# This calls A1.py (see below)
result = subprocess.run([sys.executable, Path(processes_dir, "A1.py")], input="1\n2", capture_output=True, text=True)

# If an error is raised, it's written to output.txt; stdout is written to output.txt
if result.stderr:
    with open(outfile, 'a') as f:
        f.write("{0}\n\n".format(result.stderr))
else:
    with open(outfile, 'a') as f:
        f.write("{0}\n\n".format(result.stdout))
```

The subprocess.run invokes the following simple script:

```
x1 = int(input())
x2 = int(input())
print(x1+x2)
```

This runs just fine. I'm trying to work out how to convert this into an executable (.exe) using Pyinstaller. In the appropriate directory, I run:

```
pyinstaller --onefile test.py
```

This builds test.exe successfully. When I run test.exe (either from cmd or double-clicking on the file) it opens with no errors, produces an empty output.txt and then simply hangs indefinitely. It appears subprocess.run doesn't work properly with pyinstaller. Any ideas/suggestions to get test.exe to work with pyinstaller?

Comment: Have you installed the `pyinstaller` from `PyPi`? if so try uninstalling it and install the one from github `pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip`

Comment: According to the pyinstaller docs `sys.executable` isn’t the Python interpreter like it is for normal Python code, so using it to run a python script may not work as you hope. Try printing it see what it is. https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html

Comment: @IceBear Yes I installed it from `PyPi` using `pip install pyinstaller`. I believe it's the same installation as the one offered on github.

Comment: @barny It prints `C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Pyinstaller_test\test.exe` which is indeed the location to test.exe, so that does seem to be the issue. PyInstaller should bundle a python application (and all required dependencies) so how do I direct test.exe to invoke this bundled python? I probably could direct this to my installation of python, but that defeats the whole purpose of bundling this as an exe in the first place, as I intend to share this with users without a python installation.

Comment: Your code can import the python code and execute something from it, or you can eval it to execute something in it.

Comment: @barny Can you provide an example? I'm confused on how to do this as `A1.py` requires user input (which `subprocess.run` easily provides with the `input` parameter).

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that, when the script is not compiled, `sys.executable` returns the *python* executable file (`C:\Users\randomuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python38`), but when the code is compiled, sys.executable returns the .exe file you havce made. So, your .exe file calls itself, calling itself again infinite times, hainging.

You could solve this in two different (easy) ways:

1. (Less recommended if you want to distribute your exe file, because it dependes on a python installation):
   Replace `sys.executable` with `'python'`. This will ensure the script is executed with Python rather than with your own .exe file if compiled:

   ```
    result = subprocess.run(['python', Path(processes_dir, "A1.py")], input="1\n2", capture_output=True, text=True)
   ```
2. You can import the `A1.py` script (ensuring the script is in the same folder as the executable, and making the main code to be in a function called main returning the result as a string):

Then, you'll be able to run `import A1`, and call the main procedure running `A1.main()`:

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import A1
from pathlib import Path

# This is for pyinstaller (as main_dir = sys.path[0] won't work)
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    main_dir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
else:
    main_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

processes_dir = Path(main_dir, "processes")
outfile = Path(main_dir, "output.txt")

# Initialize the output text file
with open(outfile, 'w') as f:
    f.write('')

# This calls A1.py (see below)
result = A1.main()

# The output is written into output.txt.

with open(outfile, 'a') as f:
    f.write("{0}\n\n".format(result))
```

You could consider capturing error tracebacks with try-except clause and with the traceback module

The pyinstaller command then should be: `pyinstaller --onefile test.py --add-data "A1.py;."`